# How to slide bootstrap carousel manually using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have gone through whole bootstrap carousel [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel) but couldn't find way to manually slide bootstrap carousel.
Any help is appreciated.

Link to bootstrap carousel that I am trying to slide manually:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

Code with data-interval set to false:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
       <p>hii</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
       <p>hello</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <p>There</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I have couple of tabs on my page. And based on the tab that is selected I want particular slide to be visible. And then user can use < or >. To move through other slides.

Comment: Where is your code? What you have tried?

Comment: @VicJordan I am not finding any reference to try. Its just a simple bootstrap carousel.

Comment: What do you mean by **manually slide** here? Because it is already sliding manually when I am clicking on the arraows `<` & `>`

Comment: I want to slide carousel using my own JavaScript based on condition.Let me clearly tell my requirement: I have couple of tabs on my page. And based on tab selected I want particular slide to be visible.

Comment: What is your condition? Mention it in your question

Comment: Updated question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its already stated there.
Please Set

```
interval: false
```

It will stop auto-cycle
After that If you want to go to any slide manually or whatever code you want you can do this.

```
    $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
       $('#myCarousel').carousel('what slide I want')
    })
```

Comment: Yes, I did. Question is I want to slide it using JavaScript.

Comment: Oh Sorry my bad

Comment: @TavishAggarwal What do you want If you want to manually slide it or do something you can use bootstrap async methods like the one which fired when carousel is invoked

Comment: Added Edit @TavishAggarwal

Answer (score -2):

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fd/47/68/fd47684651aa6d7b49c7bbdb11eb22cd.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bd/36/78/bd36788309d826f60f33adad7ccc86ad.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aWWlLEWZLec/XEKndGLgbJI/AAAAAAAAAJY/0ztnnpbFpb8b2e74OaWeOBuKykSJFa3VwCLcBGAs/s1600/Navigation%2Bbar-1.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: This question is about [bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel)